# JS WebdriverIO search for broken links on a website page

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

tell me please, I can’t get broken links at the output, it gives an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')` This is due to an internal link `<a href="/status_codes">here</a>`, I have specified in the file wdio.conf `baseUrl: 'https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/'`, anyway on the link `<a href="/status_codes">here</a>` I get `rejected`

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
describe('Broken link test', async () => {

    it('Check the page for broken links', async () => {
        const errorsUrls = [];
        await browser.url('status_codes/200');
        const urls = (await $$('a').map(link => link.getAttribute("href")));

        const requests = urls.map(url  => fetch(url));
        const responses = await Promise.allSettled(requests);
        const errors = responses.filter(r => r.status === 'rejected').map(r => r.reason.url)

        responses.forEach((element) => {
           console.log(element.status)
            if (element.status === 'rejected') {
                errorsUrls.push(element);
            }
        });

        for (const errorsUnless of errorsUrls) {
           console.log('>>>>>>>>>>8888' + errorsUnless.value.url)
        }

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `urls` array may have elements without https/http scheme for all internal links. Unlike `browser.url`, your `fetch` will not have access to `baseUrl` and so gets rejected.

You can modify your code as below.

Replace

```
const requests = urls.map((url) => fetch(url));
```

with

```
const base = 'https://yourbaseurl.com';
const requests = urls.map(url => {
  if(!url.startsWith('http')) {
    url = base + url;
  }
  return fetch(url);
})
```